# OSX Mountain Lion Homebrew doctor error importing cdo

Tags: homebrew, osx-mountain-lion

G'day legends,

I've been suffering horribly with Homebrew on OSX Mountain Goat lately.

I wanted to get numpy and scipy going and it has been hell.

I ended up removing homebrew completely. Somewhere in the middle I did something wrong.

Now I get this:

```
192-168-1-105:local holografix$ brew doctor
Error: Failed to import: cdo
Your system is raring to brew.
```

Comment: Have you tested Homebrew despite the message? I have the same issue on a clean Homebrew install on ML, but it seems to be working just fine. The "Your system is raring to brew" message also implies that it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug. (https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/14409).

For fix it you can edit /usr/local/Library/Formula/cdo.rb (for example with nano text editor). You need to replace the line

```
"options 'enable-grib2', 'Compile Fortran bindings'"
```

by

```
"option 'enable-grib2', 'Compile Fortran bindings'"
```

It was "options", but we need "option".

Comment: SkyFox thanks so much! I'm really beginning to think that Macports might have been a better choice, I had used it before and it always worked alright!